# proc contents out size sas

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a meta data table for all the tables in the "xyzfolder" using the proc contents function (see below for more details). When the table "all" is created, I noticed that the "file size" column is missing. As in for table ABC in xyzfolder, I would like to look at a column "file size" to see if table ABC is greater than 1 GB.

```
proc contents data=xyzfolder._all_ out =work.all; 
run;
```

Comment: I removed the SQL tag because this question has nothing to do with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is to use the dictionary tables.  You can do that in SQL like so, or in regular SAS using `sashelp.vtable`.

```
proc sql;
  create table all as
    select * from dictionary.tables
    where libname='SASHELP';
quit;
```

If filesize is known to SAS it will be listed here in the column `filesize`.  If it's not known to SAS, you will need to provide some more information as to your operating system, the location and type of the libname, etc. to get useful responses.